# How to sort the file in such a way that join command accepts the sorted file?

Tags: sort, join

I sorted two files and used `join` to merge the columns of the files according to row names.

Commands I used

`sort file 1 > file1_sort`
`sort file 2 > file2_sort`
`join   -o auto   -e '0'   -a 1   -a 2   -1 1   -2 1 file1_sort file2_sort`

error I got:
join:file2_sort:174: is not sorted: rna138  2.40470772961855
join:file1_sort:476: is not sorted: rna3936 1.43431338046894

I checked file2_sort and it was like this

```
rna13804        0.335430469576339
rna138  2.40470772961855`
```

when I edit the file by rearranging the order as

```
 `rna138  2.40470772961855
  rna13804        0.335430469576339`
```

the join command runs and stops again at another line that is not sorted.

I have 1000 rows and many files to merge. How to sort the file in such a way that join command accepts the sorted file?

Comment: Try `sort -n`: compare according to string numerical value (see `man sort`).

Comment: I tried `sort -n` and also `sort -g`, `sort -h`. But the error occurs.

Comment: `sort -n -k 1.1,2.3` sorts by the first three positions (`rna` before `rnb`), then uses the rest of the line to sort numerically. Does that work?

Comment: AFAIK `sort` expects the join fields to be sorted lexically (i.e. the default `sort` - **not** numerical). The issue *might* be your locale; it's hard to say without samples of both files. Try `LC_COLLATE=C sort` instead of plain `sort`

Comment: `LC_COLLATE=C sort` worked.

Comment: Glad this got solved. Just as a note for anyone else reading this question: `man join` gives `sort -k 1b,1` as an example. I had a more complicated file where I actually had to use this option. In particular, you must use "-b" (ignore blanks when sorting), and, for some reason, you need the final ",1" so sorting other columns won't somehow mess up join (I can't explain why this would happen, but it did happen to me). Possibly helpful code: https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/BACKUP/Makefile.bulk2 (the history of this file shows things I tried that didn't work)